# Knaap AMS 250 w bafang rear hub motor

Tags: cable

Hi can anyone tell me if I slice this 8-pin cable that comes out of the controller so that I could connect a 5-pin display by matching color to color? I am not sure what all the 8 wires are for in this cable. Any help please? maybe a diagram a photo or how to?[image]

Comment: Matching colour to colour is almost guaranteed not to work; you need the specs for the controller and your display so you make sure you tie +5V to +5V (for example) regardless of colour.